# Configure chrome managed storage on MacOS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am trying to use the chrome.managed.storage storage API in my extension in order to have some initialization data at extension startup.

For testing on MacOs I used this [documentation](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions/).

I used the exact configuration as in the documentation and of course I changed the manifest id to the test extension:
[image]

The test extension used is [Show Managed Storage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-managed-storage/ongnjlefhnoajpbodoldndkbkdgfomlp/related?hl=en&pli=1).

I followed the instruction in the documentation and here is the output of dscl:
[image]

After reloading the policies there is no managed storage associated with my test extension:
[image]

On Windows it worked fine. Did anyone managed to configure the managed storage on MacOs?

**EDIT:**

---

The schema defined in the extension manifest needs to be respected. In case of the test extension we have these values defined in the schema:

[image]

I imported this config plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.google.Chrome.extensions.ongnjlefhnoajpbodoldndkbkdgfomlp</key>
    <dict>
      <key>string</key>
      <dict>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>always</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <string>hello</string>
      </dict>
      <key>boolean</key>
      <dict>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>always</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

This is what I get when I execute `dscl -u admin_username /Local/Default -mcxread /Computers/local_computer`

```
App domain: com.google.Chrome.extensions.ongnjlefhnoajpbodoldndkbkdgfomlp
Key: boolean
State: always
Value: 1

App domain: com.google.Chrome.extensions.ongnjlefhnoajpbodoldndkbkdgfomlp
Key: string
State: always
Value: hello
```

Is the imported config correct? I tried also not adding the `state` key but the import is not successful.

Comment: Enable the checkbox "Show policies with no value set".

Comment: No, it's not there

Comment: The first screenshot with gihm... id is from the documentation. I wrote in the description that the extension id is correctly changed.
Manigest id ongn... is from the this test extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-managed-storage/ongnjlefhnoajpbodoldndkbkdgfomlp/related?hl=en&pli=1

Comment: My bad, reading the images is inconvenient, so I suggest to properly paste the text at least to avoid future downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run the following command:

```
sudo mcxrefresh -n username
```